# CheckBoxList is not visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

pls advice -

CheckBoxList is not visible - it must show 3 roles (existing for the moment):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="admin.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="HSE_Monitoring_Application.admin.admin" title="Untitled Page" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

    <h3>Role Manager</h3>

    <div>
        Enter UserName: 
        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:Button ID="LookupBtn" runat="server" Text="Search" />

    </div>

    <div class="roleList">
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="RoleList" runat="server" Visible=true>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>

    <div>
        <asp:button ID="UpdateBtn" text="Update" Visible="false" runat="server" />
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

in result - it must show 3 checkboxes with 3 Roles - Admins, Approvers, Auditors and button 'Update'.These Roles exist.
With the help of Roles checkbox controls - admin can manage Role Membership on pages.

It shows only label(Enter UserName) with textbox and button (Search).
Please reply. I can provide needed files if necessary.
I spent a lot of time for fixing this issue.

with regards!

---

The content of 'admin.aspx.cs' is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace HSE_Monitoring_Application.admin
{
    public partial class admin : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private void PopulateRoleList(String userName)
        {

            RoleList.Items.Clear();

            string[] roleNames;
            //string roleName="";

            roleNames = Roles.GetAllRoles();

            Response.Write(roleNames);

            foreach (string roleName in roleNames)
            {
                ListItem roleListItem = new ListItem();
                roleListItem.Text = roleName;
                roleListItem.Selected = Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, roleName);
                RoleList.Items.Add(roleListItem);
            }
        }



        private void UpdateRolesFromList()
        {
            foreach (ListItem roleListItem in RoleList.Items)
            {
                string roleName = roleListItem.Value;
                string userName = TxtUserName.Text;
                Boolean enableRole = roleListItem.Selected;

                if (enableRole == true && Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, roleName) == false)
                {
                    Roles.AddUserToRole(userName, roleName);
                }
                else if (enableRole == false && Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, roleName) == true)
                {
                    Roles.RemoveUserFromRole(userName, roleName);
                }
            }
        }

        private void LookupBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateRoleList(TxtUserName.Text);
            UpdateBtn.Visible = true;
        }

        private void UpdateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateRolesFromList();
            PopulateRoleList(TxtUserName.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code please?

Comment: Are you binding anything to RoleList in your code-behind?

Comment: How are you binding your CheckBoxList ? I noticed the `Visible=true` without double quotations , it should be `Visible = "True"`

Comment: changed to - Visible="true" - Failed.

Comment: could Response.Write(roleNames) break your html code?

Comment: Isn't roleList a css class where display is set to hidden?

Answer (score 0):

First, I notice from your code that there is no place where you called the method `PopulateRoleList` when your page loads - `Page_Load` is absent in your code. This is called when you click `LookupBtn_Click`. So initially, the CheckBoxList is empty.

Secondly, *if the DataSource or Items of a CheckBoxList is empty, the CheckBoxList is not visible* on the page. (*Still looking why this is so*)

**The Conclusion is:** Verify that your Roles array is not empty.

Your populate method should be this simple

```
 private void PopulateRoleList(String userName)
 {
     string[] roleNames = Roles.GetAllRoles();
     RoleList.DataSource = roleNames;  //if this is empty, CheckBoxList is not visiblie
     RoleList.DataBind();

     foreach (ListItem item in RoleList.Items)
     {                
          string roleName = item.Value; //Or item.Text;
          item.Selected = Roles.IsUserInRole(userName, roleName);
     }
 }
```